# Customize Item.Clear() of the CheckedListBox

Tags: c#, winforms

I am looking to customize Item.Clear() of the CheckedListBox and I have been working on this for some time but am unable to access the Clear Method to override it. The below code returns no suitable Method found to override.

```
public partial class cLBEx : CheckedListBox
{
    public cLBEx()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs pe)
    {
        base.OnPaint(pe);
    }

    public override void Clear()
    {

    }

}
```

Any assistance would be much appreciated

Comment: You can only Clear the Items collection. What exactly is you goal??

Comment: What would your `Clear()` do differently?

Comment: Are you trying to remove all items or uncheck all items?  Use following to uncheck :  for (int i = 0; i < checkedListBox1.Items.Count; i++) { checkedListBox1.SetItemChecked(i, false); }

Comment: Thank you for your prompt responses. Effectively I am experimenting with creating a custom control that mimics a combobox but utilising a TextBox with a dropdown arrow and checkedListBox as the dropdown. Everything would appear to be working exactly as I require with one exception. If I Clear the items from the checkedListBox dropdown the selected items text displayed within the textbox is not cleared. I was looking to see if I could utilise the clear() method to also clear the textbox.

Comment: You can always write the Clear method (without the override) and use it to do both..  Will others use your control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because my comment on the last answer was deleted with the post:

Clear Method is Part of `ListBox.ObjectCollection` that's why you cant override it in any subclassed `CheckedListBox` or `ListBox` Types. You have to subclass `ListBox.ObjectCollection` and then Subclass `CheckedListBox` to change the Type of the underlying Item Property.

Edit, for a smarter and quicker way, you can use an Extensionmethod like

```
public static void ClearCollection(this ListBox.ObjectCollection list) {
 // do work!
}
```